# How can I use conditional statements to manipulate information while using io.write?

Tags: lua, conditional-statements

I want the player to be able to choose a character so I print a list of four characters.

```
   print("Choose a character")
   print("1. the rocker")
   print("2. the vocalist")
   print("3. the drummer")
   print("4. the bassist")
```

I then use the io.write function to allow the player to make a choice between characters 1 and 4. I save the choice in the menu_option variable. I know that I would have to add some code for error handling but I am not worried about that at the moment

```
io.write('Which character do you choose?')
menu_option = io.read()
```

I now want to create some conditionals to create a variable that will define the title of the character that the player chose.

```
if menu_option == 1 then
character = ("the rocker")

elseif menu_option == 2 then
character = ("the vocalist")

elseif menu_option == 3 then
character = ("the drummer")

elseif menu_option == 4 then
character = ("the bassist")
end
```

This is where my code begins to fail. The write function is correctly writing the choice (from 1 to 4) to the menu_option variable but my if statement block is not correctly functioning. The character variable remains nil.

What am I doing wrong? Thanks for any help you all can give me.

Comment: `if menu_option == "1" then`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The wrong is that io.read() always returning a string.
You expected a number in your if conditions.
Now you have to correct each if like @Egor wrote in the comment or do...

```
menu_option = tonumber(io.read())
```

...and let the if' check for numbers

After that you can do in case of NaN (Not a Number) or entering nothing (i.e. hit only RETURN/ENTER)...

```
io.write('Which character do you choose? ')
local menu_option = tonumber(io.read())

if menu_option == empty then menu_option = math.random(4) end
-- empty == nil but better (human) readable
```

...for a random selection.

Moreover i suggest using more local variable declarations so it looks like...

```
-- File: character.lua
local character = ''
print("Choose a character:")
print("[1] the rocker")
print("[2] the vocalist")
print("[3] the drummer")
print("[4] the bassist")

io.write('Which character do you choose? ')
local menu_option = tonumber(io.read())

if menu_option == empty then menu_option = math.random(4) end

if menu_option == 1 then
 character = "the rocker"
elseif menu_option == 2 then
 character = "the vocalist"
elseif menu_option == 3 then
 character = "the drummer"
elseif menu_option == 4 then
 character = "the bassist"
end

print('You choosed:',character:upper())

-- Possible return values...
-- return character:upper(), menu_option -- Two values: first=string second=number
-- return os.exit(menu_option) -- Number can examined on bash with ${?}
-- ^-> Example: lua character.lua || printf '%d\n' ${?}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I was doing a tutorial and got ahead of myself. The author eventually explained exactly what you both had explained. I learned that next time I should finish watching a tutorial (or at least the whole section) before I get ahead of myself and start asking simple questions.

Thanks again!

Comment: The Truth has to be repeated ;-)